# G-graphs and Cayley graphs

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

with which kinds of group we can make a G-graph(Bretto 2011) which are hamiltonian Cayley graph?

Comment: Are you referring to this paper?  Bretto and Faisant, Cayley graphs and G-graphs: some applications, *J. Symbolic Comput.* 46 (2011), no. 12, 1403–1412.

Comment: thank you. actually I am searching for a good subject for my work on PhD thesis. so I saw that paper of Bretto and I was interested in. but I would be so apriciated if you help me find a kind of good subject for work. something like power graph, degree graph ...are also good. I want to make a graph based on group

Comment: As Angelo has commented on your other question: MO is not a replacement for PhD supervision